# c sscanf check if there is more than one parameter in line?

Tags: c, scanf

Is there some c trick that's been already built inside one of libraries or do I have to write something to check it manually?
Following code helps me detect if too low number of parameters were read, but not too many because the sscanf stops for example on 3 even if there are 5 parameters in that line and goes to another line.

```
 if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", &elements->start_state_) != 1)
 {
   //code
 }
```

P.S. keep in mind that I'm doing line by line input.

This program would operate good if 0 or 1 parameters were read, but more than 1 is not detected and represents a problem to me.

Comment: Are all the "parameters" in the lines you read integer numbers? Then you can use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol), it will give you a pointer to the next character after the number, and after skipping leading white-space you can use it in a loop to read multiple numbers. Or perhaps use [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to split the input on space.

Comment: I was affraid the strtok solution would not work with multiple spaces, fortunately it did :)! good one

Answer (score 2):

If I have correctly understood, you want to know if there is *anything* after the last used parameter on a line - I assume you got the line through a call to `fgets`.

What I generally did facing that problem was just try to decode a single non blank character after last parameter:

```
char dummy[2]; /* save space for terminating null */
...
if(sscanf(buffer, "%d%1s", &elements->start_state_, dummy) != 1) {
    ...
}
```

If there is nothing (too less parameters) on the line `sscanf` will return a too low value, and if there is at least one non blank parameter, it will return 1 too high.

Answer (score 1):

Use `"%n"` to save the number of characters scanned so far.  Note that `" "` and `"%n"` cannot fail nor do they contribute to`sscanf()` result.

```
int n = 0;

// Allowing whitespace after the number
sscanf(buffer, "%d %n", &elements->start_state_, &n);

// or
// Dis-allowing whitespace after the number
sscanf(buffer, "%d%n", &elements->start_state_, &n);

if (n == 0 || buffer[n]) {
  // problem with buffer
}
```